# Group By Clause show aggregate method error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am try to use this SQL query but showing aggregate method error please solve this issue. I am using this query in stored procedure . thanks in advace

```
BEGIN
    SELECT CustomerName + ' - ' + StoreName                                                                     AS 'CustomerName',
           CreateDate                                                                                           AS 'OrderDate',
           DeliveryDate,
           RegDelDate,
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), WeekStart, 101) + ' - ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, 6, WeekStart), 101) AS 'WeekName',
           TotalCost,
           TotalCount,
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), O.OrderId)                                                                      AS 'OrderId',
           Comment,
           CASE
             WHEN TicketNo IS NULL
                   OR TicketNo = '' THEN 'DDM'
             ELSE TicketNo
           END                                                                                                  AS 'TicketNo',
           [Status]
    FROM   [Order] O
           INNER JOIN Store S
             ON S.StoreID = O.StoreId
           INNER JOIN Customer C2
             ON C2.CustomerID = O.CustId
           INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(OrderQty)            AS TotalCount,
                              SUM(OrderQty * CaseCost) AS TotalCost,
                              OrderId
                       FROM   OrderItem OI
                       GROUP  BY OrderId) OI
             ON OI.OrderId = O.OrderId
           INNER JOIN AllWeeks
             ON WeekNo = [Week]
                AND YearNo = [Year],
           OrderItem OI1
    GROUP  BY O.CreateDate
END
```

Comment: You must add to the group by any column from the select which doesn't use any aggregate function.

Comment: thanks for edit i am using stack overflow first time

Comment: i am adding "CreateDate" this is exist in select

Comment: Also you are doing a presumably incorrect cartesian join on `OrderItem OI1`

Comment: will you please edit query for me .. unable to understand @ Martin Smith

Comment: Say that there is more than one row with the same `O.CreateDate` value, but different values in the other columns in the `SELECT` list - how is SQL Server meant to decide what value to show for those columns? What did you think the `GROUP BY` would do?

Comment: it is returing duplicate records

Comment: Okay, good, it's returning "duplicates" - if those are 100% duplicates across all columns, you need `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`. If they're "duplicates" for `CreateDate` but other columns are different, then you need to give us the rules for *which* values to select for those other columns. SQL Server will not "guess".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using aggregation then a column either needs to be in the group by or the aggregate

The group by does not make sense as you are going to have multiple customers and customers does not really aggregate.

I am guessing you want something like this

```
  SELECT O.CustomerName, O.CreateDate, sum(TotalCost) as 'SumCost', sum(TotalCount)  as 'SumCount'                             
    FROM   [Order] O
           INNER JOIN Store S
             ON S.StoreID = O.StoreId
           INNER JOIN Customer C2
             ON C2.CustomerID = O.CustId
           INNER JOIN (SELECT SUM(OrderQty)            AS TotalCount,
                              SUM(OrderQty * CaseCost) AS TotalCost,
                              OrderId
                       FROM   OrderItem OI
                       GROUP  BY OrderId) OI
             ON OI.OrderId = O.OrderId
           INNER JOIN AllWeeks
             ON WeekNo = [Week]
                AND YearNo = [Year],
           OrderItem OI1
    GROUP  BY O.CustomerName, O.CreateDate
```